# Can a Django project be hosted in Firebase? If yes, give me an idea

Tags: django, python-3.x, firebase, django-rest-framework, hosting

I know to host my Django projects in pythonanywhere or something else. But, I need to know is that possible to host a Django project in Firebase Hosting Services.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Firebase Hosting only supports static content.  It does not give you a way to run any backend code.  You can use Firebase Hosting to proxy some requests to a Cloud Functions backend, but Cloud Functions provides its own way of handling HTTP requests.